# How to update ResponseBody dynamically in a test script?

Tags: javascript, postman

In Postman I'm able to connect to an API but one of the fields it's returning (a uri) is not quite right for what I need. It includes the path but not the host. I'd like to use write a test script to intercept the response and update the uri myself but it's not working at all.

```
var imageURL=pm.variables.get("ImageServiceUrl");

var data=JSON.parse(responseBody);

var encoded;
data.forEach(function(arrayItem) {
  arrayItem.uri = imageURL + arrayItem.uri;
  console.log(arrayItem.uri);
})


//Using the response object directly doesn't do anything
pm.response.body=data;
//responseBoby also does nothing
responseBody=JSON.stringify(data);
```

No matter what I do the Response Body never gets updated.  Is this even possible?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: What is `reponse.body`?

Comment: @guest271314 This is the response object in the Postman Collection from here: http://www.postmanlabs.com/postman-collection/Response.html